# Reader for txt files

Tags: plain-text, reader

I want to read .txt files but not editing them.

Not in the command line, so not more and similar utilities.

I would like to open like if it were a .pdf file, but without converting to a PDF, so not pandoc and similiar utilities.

My case is: I have downloaded all the RFCs so I'm looking for the most convenient way to read them offline.

Comment: Cant you mark them read only snd then use anything ( even an editor) to read them. Personally  I  use a file comparing program called beyond control. And i just use this often to read files. Just keep going down the list, press enter to view, escape to exit and then down arrow. Which OS please

Answer (score 0):

Like a tabbed interface or a tree browser interface to make switching back and forth through files easier? Can do that in notepad++ like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694364/file-tree-view-in-notepad

Effectively you manage the directory like a project. and if you do not want to be able to edit, then mark them all read only. Curious though why editing ability detracts from reading.

Past that you have said what you do not want a lot, and little about the feature you need other than being able to read text.

oh, and welcome to the forum :-)